# After Installation in Dual Boot (UEFI), SSD Partitions Management

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I installed ubuntu in dual-boot in a laptop with pre-installed Windows 8.1 (uefi) with 500gb HDD and 32gb SSD. During and after installation everything went Ok, but as recommended, I leaved the SSD alone and only used the HDD. Now after the installation (couple of months after) **I wanna make use of my SSD and I wanna know if I can change it's partitions without concerning and if `bcache` has any use in this case. Taking in consideration that I wanna make the best use of it for Ubuntu not Windows.**

> Note: It was highly recommended that UEFI or SecureBoot Mode was
>   disabled to install Ubuntu in dual-boot, since I didn't figured out
>   how to disable it (there wasn't any option in BIOS) I leaved the
>   fast-boot off and SecureBoot unchanged (therefore ON). As said
>   everything went OK so I leaved that aside, occasionally when I'm
>   booting Windows it goes to a repair screen then turn off the laptop, I
>   start it again and everything goes fine. I am just saying it because I
>   don't know if it influence in anything.

Screenshots of my actual partitions

(C: ) and (D: ) are both for Windows, the others I have no idea.

I didn't know a proper way to make the partitions then set it to do automatically during the installation. Therefore all other partitions are strange to me (Recovery, Restore, etc...).

[image: 500GB HDD with both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu]

[image]

Comment: Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSD partitioning, after Dual-Boot with Windows 8.1 (UEFI)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659881/ssd-partitioning-after-dual-boot-with-windows-8-1-uefi)